# Live USB data gets lost on Restart

Tags: live-usb, persistence

I am crawling some data using Apache Nutch and storing it on my USB Drive. The OS itself is Ubuntu Live Boot OS. But for every restart or shutdown I am losing my data. I also tried suspending my Ubuntu user still data was not visible when I reinserted my live USB.

Is there any way I can keep the data intact and does not loose and application settings installations when I do restart Ubuntu.

Used USB installer provided by pendrivelinux.com at http://pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button

Comment: Used USB installer provided by pendrivelinux.com at
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button

Answer (score 2):

Universal USB Installer is a Live Linux USB Creator that allows you to choose from a selection of Linux Distributions to put on your USB Flash Drive.

The Universal USB Installer is easy to use. Simply choose a Live Linux Distribution, the ISO file, your Flash Drive and, Click Install. Other features include; **Persistence** (if available), and the ability to fat32 format the flash drive (recommended) to ensure a clean install.

Upon completion, you should have a ready to run bootable USB Flash Drive with your select Linux version installed.

You need to make the USB installation Persistent

Additional information Here : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Comment: i have already installed it.. do not want to reinstall it all over again.. is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: also , i have Set 2GB for the persistent file.